# Django crispy-forms TemplateDoesNotExist

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-crispy-forms

I am new in Django, so I was trying structures in the book "Django for Beginners by William S Wincent" about how to attach crispy forms to my signup page!

However, in the middle of my progress in the topic, I faced to TemplateDoesNotExist exception! Error:
[Error description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mUYzn.png)

Here is where the error raises:
[Error description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0AVe4.png)

And here is my settings.py configuration:

```
...

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'crispy_forms',
    "accounts",
    "pages",
]
CRISPY_TEMPLATE_PACK = "bootstrap4"
...
```

**django = 4.2.3**
**django-crispy-forms = 2.0**

I've tried to create a Sign Up Page, configuring its views and urls properly to host crispy_forms in my project.

Also crispy_forms(Version 2.0) is installed.
[Packages installed in my virtual environment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lPHSK.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `'crispy_bootstrap4'` to the `INSTALLED_APPS` as well:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'crispy_forms',
    'crispy_bootstrap4',  # 🖘 add crispy_bootstrap4
    'accounts',
    'pages',
]
```

If you use bootstrap-4 templates, you need to load the app that exposes these templates for the render engine.

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work. Passes the error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'crispy_bootstrap4'`. Btw I made the project as a GitHub repository, you can see the source code there. [Source code](https://github.com/ToghrolTP/django-news)

Comment: @Toghrol: you should also install `crispy-bootstrap4` as requirement: https://pypi.org/project/crispy-bootstrap4/